# Reset (clear) a table in Doctrine ORM 2.5 and Symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-query, symfony3.x

Using Smyfony 3.4 and Doctrine ORM 2.5 (mySql) I am looking for a way to "reset" a table.

By reset I mean I want to delete all entries of that table and reset the autoincrement for the id column. Basically I want to get the initial state when the table was first created.

This should be used when re-filling a table from an update source.

There probably is a way to do this using the query builder but I couldn't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
$cmd = $em->getClassMetadata($className);
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$dbPlatform = $connection->getDatabasePlatform();
$connection->beginTransaction();
try {
    $connection->query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
    $q = $dbPlatform->getTruncateTableSql($cmd->getTableName());
    $connection->executeUpdate($q);
    $connection->query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');
    $connection->commit();
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
    $connection->rollback();
}
```

And if you want to reset the auto-increment, just do:

```
$con->exec('ALTER TABLE ' . $cmd->getTableName() . ' AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;');
```